# Why do for-loop and function take different time in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

Let's say I want to print a vector x using a `for-loop`

```
         x <- 1:1000

         ptm <- proc.time()
         for(i in x){
             print(i)
              }
         proc.time() - ptm

       user  system elapsed 
       0.62    0.02    0.62
```

I can also write a function to do the same thing:

```
    print.fun <- function(x){
                   return(x)
                 }

      ptm <- proc.time()
      print.fun(x)
      proc.time() - ptm

     user  system elapsed 
      0.24    0.00    0.23
```

Why do these two approaches take different time even though they are doing the same thing i.e. print x one after the other?

Comment: They don't do the same thing. `print.fun` prints `x`, and the for loop creates a new object for each individual element of `x` and prints it.

Comment: `for loop creates a new object for each individual`: but I am not creating any object in the for loop. As in I am not doing  `j <- i; print(j)`. Sorry if I got the wrong

Comment: First one is printing each number one by one. Second one is printing the returned value of the function (default function behavior). You are likely calling on the function to print 1:1000 in the second method. For the first method, I'm guessing `UseMethod("print")` is called 1000x more time. Plus the overhead for the for loop is causing the time difference.

Comment: Interestingly, the for loop is faster on my machine.

Comment: Tye for loop takes .62sec. How is that faster as compared to 0.23?